# aks not showing the list of namespaces and workloads

Tags: azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to learn AKS using terraform. Created an AKS cluster using [these terraform configuration files](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureAksTerraform/tree/main/iac/010050-kube-pods-intro).

After applied, I see that the aks is not showing the namespaces are workloads on azure portal and shows me this message.

> namespaces is forbidden: User "1456657a-34b8-4930-b7af-94f462729cfk" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope: User does not have access to the resource in Azure. Update role assignment to allow access.. 'vivekx8dm@outlook.com' does not have the required Kubernetes permissions to view this resource. Ensure you have the correct role/role binding for this user or group.

[image: aks says permission denied to show namespaces]

Similarly for workloads as well.

[image: aks permission denied for workloads]

But when I try from console the following commands I get the required list of namespaces pods or services.

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get ns
kubectl get svc
```

[image: kubectl get command works]

Any idea whats happening?

### Update

I think I found the cause for the issue.

In the [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster), I have this [azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control argument reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control). Because of this, there seems to be some AD integration happening. We can observe this in the aks overview tab below. I see **Azure Ad Authentication with Azure RBAC**.

[image: azure ad authentication with RBAC]

I [removed that by commenting out that in my code](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureAksTerraform/blob/a603fa0551a8d3f147492430a77b8c8a8a823f5b/iac/010050-kube-pods-intro/tf7-aks-cluster.tf#L116) and run that again. This time I see the following.

[image: local accounts with kubernetes RBAC]

As you can see the contrast its, **Local accounts with kubernetes RBAC**.

Now its showing the namespace, workload stuff as expected.

[image: aks namespaces in azure portal]

The workloads now.

[image: aks workloads in azure portal]

Need to understand this AD more.

Answer (score 1):

***When I tried to reproduce the issue ,noted that we have different kinds of authentication and authorization mechanisms***

1. **AUTHENTICATING LOCAL ACCOUNTS FOR USER & ADMIN ACCESS / AUTHORIZATION RBAC**

   `az aks create -g RG_NAME -n AKS_CLUATER_NAME`

[image]

2. **AUTHENTICATING LOCAL ACCOUNTS FOR USER AND ADMIN ACCESS/AUTHORIZATION  *RBAC disabled***

`az aks create -g RG_NAME -n AKS_CLUSTER_NAME \ --disable-rbac`

[image]

3. **AUTHENTICATING AZURE AD / AUTHENTICATING KUBERNETES RBAC ONLY**

   `az aks get-credentials --resource-group RG_NAME --name AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --admin`
   `az aks get-credentials --resource-group RG_NAME --name AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --overwrite-existing`
   [image]
4. **AUTHENTICATING AZURE AD / AUTHERISATION USING KUBERNETES RBAC & AZURE RBAC/*LOCAL ACCOUNTS DISABLED***

   `az aks create -g RG_NAME -n AKS_CLUSTER_NAME \ --enable-aad \ --enable-azure-rbac \ --disable-local-accounts`

[image]

Kubernetes will not provide any built_in authorization mechanisms so,This service offers the ability to integrate with azure AD, we have different authorization and authenticating options with kubernetes and azure AD as mentioned above.